# Add item to request.Meta in Django and print it in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I wanna to add new item like request.path to request.META dictionary.

```
def sysinfo(request):

    values = request.META.items()

    values['REQUEST_PATH'] = request.path

    return render_to_response('template.html',{'values':values})
```

...and output in template:

```
{% for key,value in values %}
    [{{ key }}] => {{ value }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I've got the error: 'dict_items' object does not support item assignment. When I commented **values['REQUEST_PATH'] = request.path** then it works fine. I've tried also:

```
values.update({'REQUEST_PATH',request.path})
```

...and I've got the error: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'update'
Also I've tried to create a simple dictionary:

```
other_values = {
        "REQUEST_PATH" : request.path,
        "HOSTNAME" : request.get_host(),
        "FULL PATH" : request.get_full_path(),
        "HTTPS" : request.is_secure(),
    }
```

...and my output:

```
[H] => T
[R] => E
[F] => U
[H] => O
```

but if I will add .items to my values in for:

```
{% for key,value in values.items %}
    [{{ key }}] => {{ value }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

it works fine.

```
[HTTPS] => False
[REQUEST_PATH] => /sysinfo/
[FULL PATH] => /sysinfo/
[HOSTNAME] => django.local
```

So, how to add new item to exist request.META dictionary?

**P.S. I'm using Python 3 and Django 1.8.3**

Answer (score 1):

That's because `request.META.items()` return is of type `dict_items` (sort of generator). You need to turn it into a dictionary to assign another key.

```
values = dict(request.META.items())
```